# REQUEST_URI - possible to replace characters?

Tags: php, title, request-uri

I'm currently using this to give me a title based on the current URL:

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
echo"$url"; 
$url = trim ( $url ,'/' ); ?>
<title>mysite.com - <?php echo $url; ?></title>
```

Many of my urls are formatted like this:

```
mysite.com - 177_183_45_999
```

Is it possible to replace the underscores with hyphens? to acheive:

```
mysite.com - 177-183-45-999
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str_replace:

```
str_replace("_", "-", $url)
```

Example:

```
<?php echo str_replace("_", "-", $url); ?>
```

Or for a sexy oneliner:

```
$url = str_replace("_", "-", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$url = str_replace('_', '-', $url);
```